# "ERROR: The archive file is corrupt, truncated or archive parts are missing" while trying to update

Tags: joomla-3.6, upgrade

I tried all the other similar answers for the same error without success. I guess there are some kind of problem specific to the update on my host (GoDaddy). I tried:

- Upgrade normally via backend (no success)
- Upload the update package via backend / http (no success)
- Upload the update package via ftp to the administrator/tmp folder (no sucess)

All these tries gives me the same error. Any other suggestions?

Comment: From your list, I see that you upload it to `administrator` folder and I don't think that is correct. Have you tried to upload to `/tmp` (root of your site, not administrator) folder and run the Joomla! update component? --- Edit: Check [this manual](https://docs.joomla.org/J3.x:Upgrading_from_Joomla_3.4.x_to_3.5), for another alternative.

Comment: @cwps I tried to put the update package on the /tmp folder and after that I  tried the update again, with the same result (error). I noted that the normal update method put the update package inside the administrator/tmp, so, I guess this is correct. I Will check the manual you tell me. TY

Comment: @cwps The manual points three methods. The last two (B and C) are the supposed solution for me, but I do not like that. I will do some tests offline, on my local copy of joomla. Meanwhile I will wait for another answers. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally I found the solution! The problem is that, for some reason, the Joomla was saving the temporary file to the "administrator/tmp" folder **BUT** the fopen function expects a fully qualified path, so I simply edit the Joomla configuration "Path to Temp Folder", at Server Tab, to include a full path to my tmp folder.

On another words, the Joomla can **STORE** files using relative path names, but relative path names cannot be read correctly by the fopen function and so, the update always fails. To fix, I used a fully qualified path name on the "Path to Temp Folder" configuration

Answer (score 5):

I added slash before `home` in the `configuration.php`

```
public $tmp_path = '/home/host/public_html/tmp';
```

Answer (score 1):

Just upload the zip file to your Joomla website and extract it manually there. This is a manual update and it typically works smoothly when you are jumping to the immediate next version.

GoDaddy block a lot of functionality on most of their shared servers and that might be the cause of why you're seeing the problem.

Comment: I'm seeing that's the only way to get updated. I will need to do a complete backup before that

Answer (score 0):

trying to update joomla in localhost
 “ERROR: The archive file is corrupt, truncated or archive parts are missing” while

Goto configuration.php   file edit
public $tmp_path = '../tmp'; to public $tmp_path = '/tmp';

The update will working file